# Linear Phase Plot

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my text book I have the following question (it's a dutch text book, so I hope I translate the mathematical terms correctly)

Draw a Phase Plot of the following system:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=A_i y$

With:

$A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-4&0
\end{pmatrix}, 
A_2= \begin{pmatrix}
-2&2\\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
A_3= \begin{pmatrix}
3&-1\\
1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$

I have no clue on what to do. It would be very nice if someone could help me out with the first matrix and could check if I find the correct answers on the other two matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve for the eigenvalues of each and draw the phase portrait from there.

For the first matrix, $y' =  A_1 y$, we have :

$$|A_1 - \lambda I| = 0 \implies \lambda_1 = 2~i~, \lambda_2 = -2~i$$

This is a center.

The phase portrait is:

[image]

We could have also solved this system and arrived at:

$$x(t) =  c_1 \cos 2t + \dfrac{1}{2} c_2 \sin 2t  \\ y(t) = -2c_1 \sin 2t + c_2 \cos 2t$$

From this, you can parametrically plot $x(t)$ versus $y(t)$.

You can also draw nullclines and then form $\dfrac{y'}{x'}$ and add magnitude and direction for slope information and fill in the phase portrait.

Here are some notes to help with phase portraits:

- [*A quick guide to sketching phase planes*](http://mcb.berkeley.edu/courses/mcb137/exercises/Nullclines.pdf)
- [*The Phase Plane*](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-PhasePlane.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Determine the eigenvalues of the three matrices, and they will tell you stability of any equlibria the systems have, this should give you an idea of how to plot the phase space.

The only other way it to solve each system, and then plot.